# Not able to get extended options in dropdown

Tags: java, jquery, selenium, select, selenium-webdriver

I want to get all options from select button.

```
<select id="filterSel" name="filterSel" class="fixed-size" onchange="fnLoadAccountslegEnt(this.value); " onclick="closeDropDown();" size="1" style="top: 6.5px; margin: 0px; width: 58%; height: 30px; z-index: 9999; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);">                                 
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="aa" title="abcd">abcd</option>
  <option value="bb" title="xyz">xyz</option>
  <option value="More" style="color: blue;">More...</option>
</select>
```

3rd option is "More..." on pressing this more options load into the dropdown. i.e., more options are visible only now. I need to access all options using selenium `WebDriver`. Using the following code I am able to get only what is there already in the options tag to be printed on console...last option printed is "More...".
my code:

```
Select select=new Select(element_select);

List<WebElement> options = select.getOptions();
int i=1;
for(WebElement ele:options) {
    if(str.contains("More")) {  
        Filter.FilterApplied().sendKeys(str);
        Filter.FilterApplied().click();
    }
    str=ele.getText();
    System.out.println("options are :"+str);
    i++;
}
```

Error message:

> FAILED: main org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error:
>   Element ... is not clickable at point
>   (262, 84). Other element would receive the click:

Comment: If the other options only get loaded into the document after "more" is clicked, then you have to let your selenium do that click first and then get the options.

Comment: The is a problem in this case. Its a select box and also a text box. When i am giving element_select.click(); its throwing an error saying select box is not clickable instead the text box is getting clicked.

Comment: I mean its multi purpose...it can either be a dropdown or a searchbox both in same location

Comment: Are you first clicking "more"? How does tyhe code looks like after clicking more?

Comment: after manually clicking more...html code is also displaying more options in options tag.....

Comment: if all options are showing in <option value="bb" title="xyz">xyz</option> within the same Select tag, then you have to run your code after you have clicked more, have you tried that?

Comment: I have to click through script. not manual

Comment: Please post your code where you have selected the More option and add how it was unsuccessful... post any error messages or in what way it didn't work.

Comment: I have edited my question, showed how i tried to click. Also added the error I\am facing

Answer (score 0):

You could use a JSTL for loop to populate the dropdown dynamically. 
1. Add an action to the 
       `<option value="More" onclick="//goToSomeController" style="color: blue;"><%= //could be an array of options %></option>`

and from there you can populate the size of the loop and the array with options. Hope that helps.

Comment: Cant edit the webpage..Im developing a testcase using selenium

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Select` class to select the `more` option and load all the options

```
Select select = new Select(element_select);
List<WebElement> options = select.getOptions();
int size = options.size();

select.selectByValue("More");    
while ((options = select.getOptions()).size() == size);

int i = 1;
for(WebElement ele : options)
{
    str = ele.getText();
    System.out.println("options are :"+str);
    i++;
}
```

`while ((options = select.getOptions()).size() == size);` will wait for more options to load, use it this way only if you are certain there are more options coming, otherwise you will end up with infinite loop.